# How to prevent of loading images from previous results?

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide, image-loading

I am implementing search and there are cases when images of old results are loaded and applyed to new ones, so how can I prevent Glide loading images and displaying on imageView when I have new search results.

Comment: Please don't use the glide tag for questions about the Android image loading library. Use [android-glide] instead. See [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561) and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Glide to load images, you can completely skip the caching of images by using something like below:

```
Glide.with(fragment)
  .load(url)
  .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
  .into(view);
```